# Hide function is not working

Tags: jquery

I have simple hide and show function but it is not working. any help would be appreciated

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('a').click(function(){
var visible= false;         
if(visible){
$('div').hide('slow')           
}

else {
$('div').show('slow')           
}
visible=!visible;
})
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="background:#F00; width:500px; height:50px"></div>
<a href="#">hide</a>
<div class="append"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare and initialise `visible` **outside** the event handler:

```
var visible= false;  
$('a').click(function(){
   if(visible){
       $('div').hide('slow')           
   }
   else {
       $('div').show('slow')           
   }
   visible=!visible;
});
```

Otherwise you are initialising `visible` with `false` *every time* the event handler is executed, so `if(visible)` will never be true.

However, you can also use [`.toggle` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to avoid having an additional status variable:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('div').toggle();         
});
```

Comment: why it is not working when we put var visible= false inside the click function, we are swapping value it should change var visibile value

Comment: I wrote it in my answer: *you are initialising visible with false every time the event handler is executed*. Yes, you are changing `visible` at the end of the function, but then the function terminates and `visible` goes out of scope. Next time when the event handler is executed, you are calling `var visible = false;` **again** and `if(visible)` will be `false` again. Whenever you call a function, every statement inside of it is executed every time. Why do you think it should skip `var visible = false;` the second time?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a builtin hide/show method: [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/). It shows your element when it is hidden and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

The problem are these lines:

```
var visible= false;         
if(visible){
    $('div').hide('slow')           
}
```

`visible` will always be false in this context, thus your div will never be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `toggle` instead. Check out the second example here:

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Here's the example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    p { background:#dad;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:16px;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button>Toggle 'em</button>

  <p>Hiya</p>
  <p>Such interesting text, eh?</p>
  <script>
    $("button").click(function () {
      $("p").toggle("slow");
    });    
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```